# final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density is always returning a 1

Tags: android

I have posted a message before about setting the text size in pexcles.  I found some post that had using the following line to set a scale facter.

```
 final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

The text was still drawn t the same size on my acer tables, and vergin mobile phone.
My vergin phone has a resultion around 320 by 400 and the tables is something like 800 by 1100..

When I traced the code with the debuuger, scale is always pne..

code listing.

```
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  

              final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
              int size = (int) (18 * scale + 0.5f);

              paint.setTextSize(18); // cGlobals.TranslateX
              canvas.drawText("SETTINGS:", cGlobals.TranslateX(900),cGlobals.TranslateY(150), paint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code..

```
final int scale = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                     (float) 123.4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```